# Перегрузки в конструкторах классов

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, конструктор

Не нашел, что-то ответа на такой простой ответ. До этого не делал в конструкторе перегрузки таким образом (см. код ниже). В функциях/методах таким образом проходит нормально все. Вообще-то и тут все вроде нормально (на первый взгляд ;)). Компилируется без ошибок (только незаметный варнинг выходит - о нем тоже ниже). Т.е. эта информация будет полезна тем кто так сделает и даже у кого с первого раз все заработает нормально. А на самом деле так неправильно получается:

```
Camera::Camera(int width, int height)
{
    Camera(width, height, CAMERA_ENCODING::MJPEG);
}

Camera::Camera(int width, int height, CAMERA_ENCODING encoding)
{
    ... // какой-то код
}
```

А как тогда правильно делать? Неужели в верхнем конструкторе переписывать также весь код инициализации полностью надо? И еще про варнинг тут - пишет, что в верхнем конструкторе уже поле не проинициализировано. Конкретно - это ссылка на буфера. В нижнем на нее нет ест-но варнинга т.к. она тут нормально инициализируется в его коде. И в верхнем по идее должна, но оказывается это не так. Спасибо и извините если много понаписал тут.

Comment: `Camera::Camera(int width, int height) : Camera(width, height, CAMERA_ENCODING::MJPEG) { }`

Comment: Ну да!! И встречал же подобное - сейчас вспомнил (даже сейчас поищу и найду наверняка там где примерно видел такое). Но почему-то не запомнил. Спасибо - за ответ, а то так и остался бы неучем :)

Comment: Еще и прогнал/проверил все сейчас в железе тоже. (Лучше по-моему в виде ответа, а не комментария было бы. Когда в комментарии - то "не заметно" как бы. Спасибо еще раз)

Comment: Вообще-то в данном конкретном случае проще обойтись одним конструктором `Camera::Camera(int width, int height, CAMERA_ENCODING encoding = CAMERA_ENCODING::MJPEG)`

Comment: @Harry -  поправка - что-то не пошел такой вариант. Нет же теперь варианта Camera::Camera(int, int).

Comment: Как нет? Извините, вынужден в ответ дать, тут места мало...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы пытались делегировать вызов из одного конструктор в другой, то это делается так

```
Camera::Camera(int width, int height) : Camera(width, height, CAMERA_ENCODING::MJPEG)
{
  ...
}
```

Однако подобное делегирование - это свойство С++11 и выше.

До С++11 синтаксиса для делегирования вызовов конструкторов в С++ не было, и если возникала необходимость устранить повторяемость кода, то общий код по возможности приходилось выносить в обыкновенную функцию (с потерей конструкторских особенностей).

В вашем же варианте имеет место создание (и немедленное уничтожение) независимого временного объекта, не имеющего никакого отношения к конструируемому объекту.

Comment: Да спасибо большое за развернутый ответ. По сути - @PetSerAl первый дал такой ответ (похожий), но он не указал про особенность тут "С++11 и выше" (оно так и есть между прочим и это тоже очень полезный момент). Спасибо за очень важное объяснение про "создание (и немедленное уничтожение)" - это самое важное тут пожалуй. (Еще насколько помню, что C# "проглотит" такой код как привел в вопросе моментально и будет доволен - просто для информации написал). Пожалуй - Ваш ответ все-таки как раз и есть ответ на мой вопрос. Спасибо еще раз  (я помню про "птички") за развернутое объяснение.

Comment: Реально это словосочетание "имеет место создание (и немедленное уничтожение)" ключевое тут. Вроде простой случай, но компилятор так не думает. А хотел я еще написать все-таки про "вы пытались делегировать вызов из одного конструктор в другой". Пояснение нужно по этому поводу. "Делегирование" тут или нет? Пытался создать по-быстрому 2 перегрузки конструктора. Как привык в функциях/методах. И дало ошибку при работе(!), а при сборке только варнинг.

Comment: "Вроде простой случай, но компилятор так не думает." - не совсем понимаю, о чем идет речь.

Comment: т.е. он именно создает и немедленно уничтожает, а не так может показаться тут ("имеет место создание (и немедленное уничтожение)" - как у Вас написано). Т.е. совсем не простой случай (про то что смотреть надо в сгенерированый дизасм не будем говорить). А еще спрашивал насчет словосочетания "делегирование". Оно подходит здесь или нет? Спасибо.

Comment: @AleksBak: Ым... Мне не ясно, в чем вы видите разницу между "он именно создает и немедленно уничтожает" и "имеет место создание (и немедленное уничтожение)". В чем?

Answer (score 3):

В связи с отсутствием места для нормального кода в комментариях...

В данном конкретном случае не имеет смысла городить огород, достаточно создать конструктор **с третьим параметром по умолчанию**:

```
Camera::Camera(int width, int height, CAMERA_ENCODING encoding = CAMERA_ENCODING::MJPEG)
{
    ... // какой-то код
}
```

при этом если третий параметр будет указан, будет использовано переданное значение; если нет - значение по умолчанию:

```
Camera cam1(200, 300, CAMERA_ENCODING::SUPERCODE);
Camera cam2(200, 300);
```

Для `cam1` будет вызван `Camera::Camera(200, 300, CAMERA_ENCODING::SUPERCODE);`, для `cam2` - `Camera::Camera(200, 300, CAMERA_ENCODING::MJPEG);`.

Вот простейший пример -

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test(int w, int h, int code = -1)
    {
        cout << "w = " << w << "  h = " << h
             << "  code = " << code << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Test a(2,4,8);
    Test b(3,6);
}
```

дает на выходе

```
w = 2  h = 4  code = 8
w = 3  h = 6  code = -1
```

Comment: Все работает и так. Перепроверил несколько раз. Извините. В первый раз ошибку давало на отсутствующий конструктор хотя все именно так и писал. Часто такую инициализацию в функциях/методах пишу, а конструкторах ни разу. Спасибо большое, что не поленились, потратили свое время и написали еще раз подробно все.